# Corona Lua call external function

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

I have block_basic.lua that I want to call another function in touch_input.lua

block_basic.lua does:

```
local screen_touch = require( "touch_input")
local onScreenTouch = screen_touch.onScreenTouch

local function touched( event )
-- 'self' parameter exists via the ':' in function definition

print(onScreenTouch, screen_touch, event)

end
```

From what I am seeing event seems to be correct (a table), screen_touch is also correct. But the function (screen_touch.onScreenTouch) is always nil and I don't know why

In touch_input.lua I simply have:

```
local function onScreenTouch( event )
-- no 'self' parameter
```

etc. etc.

Why is it nil? Why can't I call it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what you return in `touch_input.lua`, but if you expect the first two lines of your script to work, it needs to be something like this:

```
local function onScreenTouch( event )
...
return {
  onScreenTouch = onScreenTouch
}
```

Since you don't get a run-time error on line 2, you may be returning a table already, but you need to make sure that `onScreenTouch` field of that table points to `onScreenTouch` function.

Comment: Perhaps the OP has similar code to yours but with a typo at the end, like `onScreenTouch = OnScreenTouch`.

Comment: I at the moment just want to 'call' the remote function (onScreenTouch) - but it seems to be 'nil' even though the scree_touch (from the require) seems good

Comment: Currently the function just returns TRUE. I can't call the function as it is listed as nil.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your files should be:

**touch_input.lua:**

```
local M = {}

M.onScreenTouch = function( event )
    --some code here
end

return M
```

**block_basic.lua:**

```
local screen_touch = require( "touch_input")

local onScreenTouch = screen_touch.onScreenTouch


print(onScreenTouch, screen_touch, event)
```

I tested it. It works 100%.

More info:
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/08/28/how-external-modules-work-in-corona/
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/05/a-better-approach-to-external-modules/
http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/modules
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/07/06/using-external-modules-in-corona/

Comment: Tried this; seem to make no difference

Comment: Check these links:
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/08/28/how-external-modules-work-in-corona/  
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/05/a-better-approach-to-external-modules/  
http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/modules  
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/07/06/using-external-modules-in-corona/

Comment: Hi, yes I looked at those. Even created a new function. required it in another lua file; still can't call it (just get nil)